# jQuery UI Right-Click Menu AND General Advice Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, contextmenu, right-click

So, recently I have been trying to build a user interface form builder that is almost entirely drag and drop. Kind of like Dreamweaver or visual studios I suppose. You guys can see it for yourselves [HERE!](http://caidenhome.com/jQuery_Form_Builder/builder.html) I am trying to get a right-click menu thing going, however upon getting [this](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) working, I realized that it really conflicted with both the draggable and resizable methods. I don't have to right click at all, however when I go to resize or drag, it won't let me stop it. My cursor gets stuck either resizing or dragging, and requires vigorous clicking and shaking to free it. So, I'm assuming that I need a different plugin. Does anybody know of a stress free simple right-click menu that is hopefully compatible with jquery ui? I've tried google but most of them are simply a different version of the one I've already been using.

My second question is much more vague. As I previously mentioned, I'm trying to make a form builder. I'm wondering what the best way to go about this is as I feel sort of lost. My biggest problems right now are figuring out how I'm going to parse everything into code and export it. Does anybody know of anyone else who has attempted this or something similar? Is there any sort of guide?

I know the second questions has potential to be rather annoying, so feel free to only focus on the first one. Any help is appreciated, and I thank everybody who helps me.

**EDIT:** Just realized that you guys may not know how to use the builder. So far, all you can do is drag panels out onto the building space, and then drag tables within the panels. You can resize the building space, and panels vertically, and you can resize tables both vertically and horizontally. You can move panels and tables within their parent elements. Right click a panel or table for the contextmenu.

**EDIT:** So I think I found a context menu that will suffice, [here](http://tahirhassan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-context-menu.html) it is. So, I guess that only leaves giving me advice on how to go about constructing this form builder.